# Free tool to generate all paths from a diagram

Tags: modeling, bpmn, model-based-testing

Good afternoon everyone,

Dispite a lot of research on the web I didn't found a solution that meets my need.

I need to find a free tool to modelize process (like BPMN, UML activity diagram) and generate all possible paths/combinations from the diagram.

Do you have any idea what tool can help me do that? Thank you a lot.

**Update 1**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WSbOxoa5_U

Comment: Yes a tool like that (maybe less complex to use) which show all possible paths.

Comment: I don't know easier tools, sorry. I know only this one with mentioned feature: https://jbpm.org/  use current jBPM 7.32.0.Final and LEGACY bpmn designer to use this feature, in 7.33 old designer will be disabled already :(

Comment: What do you mean by "generate all possible paths"? Does a format exist for this?

Comment: @RedBeard I updated my question with an example. I hope it will help you to understand my need. Thanks. By paths I mean combinations.

Comment: Dude, have ytou figured out how to do it? I need this so bad @Royce

Comment: Yes thanks to the response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that such tool on the shell exists. My advise would be to choose one modelling tool which

1. supports your modelisation (BPMN, Activity, etc.),
2. can be extended with a language you are confortable with (Python, Java, C#, etc.).

In this case, you will find several tools for sure.
For fun, I picked Modelio (https://www.modelio.org/),
made a small activity example,
[image]
and a Jython script for it.

```
## return first initial node in the selected activity
def getInitialPoint(act):
   for  node in act.getOwnedNode():
      if isinstance(node, InitialNode):
         return node

## parcours activity nodes
def getPaths(currentPath, currentNode): 
  for outgoing in currentNode.getOutgoing():
    node = outgoing.getTarget()
    if isinstance(node, ActivityFinalNode):
       paths.append(currentPath)
       return;
    elif  isinstance(node, DecisionMergeNode):
       getPaths(currentPath, node)  
    else:           
       getPaths(currentPath + " - "  + node.getName(), node) 

 ##Init
 init = getInitialPoint(elt)
 currentPath = init.getName()
 global paths
 paths = []
 getPaths(currentPath, init)

 ##Print founded paths
 for p in paths:
   print p
```

Hoping it helps,
EBR

Comment: Thank a lot. Could you confirmed that the result of the script is : Start - Action - Action 1 - End and Start - Action - Action 2 - End

Comment: Your solution is very nice and clear. However, I'm facing an error with your script: `AttributeError: 'org.modelio.metamodel.impl.diagrams.ActivityDiagra' object has no attribute 'getOwnedNode' in <script> at line number 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 20, in <module>
  File "<script>", line 3, in getInitialPoint
AttributeError: 'org.modelio.metamodel.impl.diagrams.ActivityDiagra' object has no attribute 'getOwnedNode'`

Comment: The result is  is : Start - Action - Action 1 and Start - Action - Action 2  but it can be updated to produce : Start - Action - Action 1 - End and Start - Action - Action 2 - End.. The script has to be launch from an Activity Element and not he diagram. Of course it can be updated to ba launche from one or another..

Comment: The result is exactly what I'm looking for. Oh ok. I will try to execute it from an Activity Element and I give you my feedback. Thank you.